# Флаг "ab+" для открытия двоичных файлов

Tags: c++

Для чего нужен флаг "ab+" при открытии двоичных файлов, в чём соль и где он полезен?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из стандарта C (7.21.5.3 The fopen function)

> a+b or ab+ append; open or create binary file for update, writing at
>   end-of-file

То есть это значение позволяет открыть существующий двоичный файл или создать новый файл для его модификации, записывая данные в конец файла.

Буква `a` в этом значение соответствует английскому слову *`append`*, которое имеет значение *`дополнить`*. То есть смысл этой опции - дополнить файл новыми данными.

Comment: в чём тогда отличие от ab

Comment: @Никита Опция "+" позволяет также читать файл. Без этой опции вы только можете писать в конец файл.

Comment: читать с конца?

Comment: @Никита Читать можете с любого места, а писать только в конец.

Comment: Так где же тогда будет указатель при открытии?

Comment: @Никита Это, как говорится, implementation-defined, то есть зависит от системы, где запускается программа. В некоторых системах указатель может сразу же после открытия устанавливаться на конец файла.

Comment: хм, интересно, ну ладно, спасибо

Comment: @Никита Не за что. За что купил, за то и продаю.:)